# How can I direct to next page and also call a function on a button click in kivy?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I have a application with two buttons on first screen. I want both the buttons to route to next page and simultaneously call their respective funtions. 
Can anyone help me with link or codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example) and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example illustrates using Kivy [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html), [`Button`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) widgets and button's `on_release` and `on_press` events.

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Create both screens. Please note the root.manager.current: this is how
# you can control the ScreenManager from kv. Each screen has by default a
# property manager that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
Builder.load_string("""
<ScreenManagement>:
    MenuScreen:
        id: name
        name: 'menu'
        
    SettingsScreen:
        id: settings
        name: 'settings'
        
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings & invoke function abc'
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
                root.manager.ids.settings.func_abc(self)    # optional: passing Button instance
                
        Button:
            text: 'Goto settings & invoke function xyz'
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
                root.manager.ids.settings.func_xyz(self)    # optional: passing Button instance

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'My settings button'
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):

    def func_abc(self, instance):
        print(f"func_abc: Called from Button with text={instance.text}")

    def func_xyz(self, instance):
        print(f"func_xyz: Called from Button with text={instance.text}")


# Create the screen manager
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What is good practice, have different screens in different files or a single file?